# merge two array and make it short

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

so I got a situation where I have two arrays
1st array contains objects some are parent and some object are child
2nd array is object of pngs 
so I want to make a resultant array with only parent items with pngs inside it and non parent items as its child array of object

```
array1=[
{id:1,name:"ABC", parentId:null, {innerObj:"value"} },
{id:2,name"XYZ"}, parentId:1, { innerObj:"value"},
{id:3,name"XYY"}, parentId:1, { innerObj:"value"},
{id:4,name"XYX"}, parentId:null,{ innerObj:"value"},
{id:5,name"PQR"}, parentId:4, { innerObj:"value"},
{id:6,name"AAA"}, parentId:4,{ innerObj:"value"}
...]
this array is of length 73
but parentItems are 16


aray2=[
{icon:"assests/icon.png", color:"fff"},
{icon:"assests/icon2.png", color:"fff"},
{icon:"assests/icon3.png", color:"fff"}
...]
this array is of length 16
```

So my question is how can I make a resultant array with length 16 and merge it like below array

```
array3=[
{id:1,name:"ABC",parentId:null,{innerObj:"value"},icon:"assests/icon.png",color:"fff",childs:
[
  {id:2,name"XYZ"},parentId:1,{innerObj:"value"},
  {id:3,name"XYY"},parentId:1,{innerObj:"value"}
]
},

{id:4,name"XYX"},parentId:null,{innerObj:"value",icon:"assests/icon2.png",color:"fff",childs:
[
  {id:5,name"PQR"},parentId:4,{innerObj:"value"},
  {id:6,name"AAA"},parentId:4,{innerObj:"value"}
]},
...]

this is resultant array3 which will be of length 16 
because parentItems and icons array(array) both are of length 16
any help would be appreciated
```

```
Note:array1 and array2 is maintained in sequence so need to bother about it
```

I tried doing this but cannot figure out the problem;

```
array1.forEach((ele, i) => {
      if (ele.parentId==null)
      {
        var parent=ele.parentId;
        array3[i] =ele;
        array3[i]["icon"] = array2[i].icon;
        array3[i]["color"] = array2[i].color; 
      }
      else
      {
        this.steps[parent]["child"] = {ele};
      }

    });
```

If my question is not clear enough just tell me i will add more explaination in it.

After looking into some syntax errors and logic I managed to solve this so I'm posting the answer in the question itself. Here is the solution to get my desired output:

```
var num =0;
    array1.forEach((ele, i) => {
      if (ele.parentId==null)
      {
        ele["childs"]=[];
        array1forEach(ele1=>{
            if(ele1.parentId==ele.id){
            ele["childs"].push(ele1);
            }
        });
        ele["icon"] = this.array2[num]["icon"];
        ele["colorc"] = this.array2[num]["color"];
        array3[num]=ele;
        num++;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder do you mind if I use that in comments? Its very thorough.

Comment: It is sad if people here dont understand your question they just close it.

Comment: @SanjaySahani, you could start with valid data. do you have infinite sub levels?

Comment: @zer00ne - Of course not, feel free!

Comment: @SanjaySahani - The problem wasn't understanding it, it was that the question was incomplete. There's no call to behave rudely as you do in the edited question. Rudeness makes it less likely you'll get help, now or in the future. How does that achieve any of your goals? Glad you figured the problem out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a hash table as reference for the parent object and an `index` for the second array's additionl information for the objects with `parentId: null`.

This approach works for sorted data and for an infinite depth of children.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1, name: "ABC", parentId: null, innerObj: "value" }, { id: 2, name: "XYZ", parentId: 1, innerObj: "value" }, { id: 3, name: "XYY", parentId: 1, innerObj: "value" }, { id: 4, name: "XYX", parentId: null, innerObj: "value" }, { id: 5, name: "PQR", parentId: 4, innerObj: "value" }, { id: 6, name: "AAA", parentId: 4, innerObj: "value" }],
    array2 = [{ icon: "assests/icon.png", color: "fff" }, { icon: "assests/icon2.png", color: "fff" }, { icon: "assests/icon3.png", color: "fff" }],
    index = 0,
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = array1.reduce((accumulator, object) => {
        if (object.parentId === null) {
            accumulator.push(hash[object.id] = { ...object, ...array2[index++] });
        } else {
            if (!hash[object.parentId].children) hash[object.parentId].children = [];
            hash[object.parentId].children.push(hash[object.id] = { ...object });
        }
        return accumulator;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```